# Issue with !file_exists failing, but file exists and loads into browser from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

The function excerpt below fails, but when I copy and past the URL in the error message into the browser the file displays just file. I've also confirmed the file is uploaded in the correct folder. This is part of a class in a library in Codeigniter 2.1.0.

What is really strange is while !file_exists fail, file_get_contents works fine. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

```
public function output() {
if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
    return "Error loading template file ($this->file).<br />";
}
$output = file_get_contents($this->file);
```

Comment: Add the path to the file so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

file_exists accesses the file over the local filesystem, while the browser uses http (and a webserver routes the request to the filesystem).
Just because one works it doesn't mean the other should work too.

Make sure the file exists by using eg. ls on the console.

Comment: Thx makes sense -- just updated question though file_get_contents works, but !file_exists doesn't -- which confuses things more.

Answer (score 2):

`file_exists` use local path, while `file_get_contents` can use both local path and URL. So if `$this->file` is an URL, it's normal that `file_exists` fails but `file_get_contents` works.

Comment: Got it -- so could this be an htaccess issue? The class containing the function in question is in a protected directory, even though the file isn't.

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean ?

Comment: What you said in the comment made sense to me. Just trying to understand why file_exists is failing and wondering if since it uses local path it's failing because the function that is looking for the file is in a directory with htaccess set to "Deny from all"

Comment: I don't think so, `htaccess` is an Apache thing, thus it does make sense only when the file is accessed via the Web (an URL)